# How do I return the result of get_mut from a HashMap or a HashSet?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to wrap a `HashMap`, as defined below, to return a mutable reference from a `HashMap`:

```rust
use std::{collections::HashMap, marker::PhantomData};

struct Id<T>(usize, PhantomData<T>);
pub struct IdCollection<T>(HashMap<Id<T>, T>);

impl<'a, T> std::ops::Index<Id<T>> for &'a mut IdCollection<T> {
    type Output = &'a mut T;
    fn index(&mut self, id: &'a Id<T>) -> Self::Output {
        self.0.get_mut(id).unwrap()
    }
}
```

And the resulting error:

```
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 54:5...
  --> src/id_container.rs:54:5
   |
54 | /     fn index(&mut self, id: &'a Id<T>) -> Self::Output {
55 | |         self.0.get_mut(id).unwrap()
56 | |     }
   | |_____^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/id_container.rs:55:9
   |
55 |         self.0.get_mut(id).unwrap()
   |         ^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 52:6...
  --> src/id_container.rs:52:6
   |
52 | impl<'a, T> std::ops::Index<Id<T>> for &'a mut IdCollection<T> {
   |      ^^
   = note: ...so that the types are compatible:
           expected std::ops::Index<id_container::Id<T>>
              found std::ops::Index<id_container::Id<T>>
```

Why can't the compiler extend the lifetime of the `get_mut`? The `IdCollection` would then be borrowed mutably.

Note that I tried using a `std::collections::HashSet<IdWrapper<T>>` instead of a `HashMap`:

```rust
struct IdWrapper<T> {
  id: Id<T>,
  t: T,
}
```

Implementing the proper borrow etc. so I can use the `Id<T>` as a key.
However, `HashSet` doesn't offer a mutable getter (which makes sense since you don't want to mutate what's used for your hash). However in my case only part of the object should be immutable. Casting a `const` type to a non-`const` is UB so this is out of the question.

Can I achieve what I want? Do I have to use some wrapper such as a `Box`? Although I'd rather avoid any indirection...

## EDIT

Ok I'm an idiot. First I missed the `IndexMut` instead of the `Index`, and I forgot the `&` when specifying the `Self::Output` in the signature.

Here's my full code below:

```rust
pub struct Id<T>(usize, PhantomData<T>);
impl<T> std::fmt::Display for Id<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.0)
    }
}

impl<T> Hash for Id<T> {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        self.0.hash(state);
    }
}

impl<T> PartialEq for Id<T> {
    fn eq(&self, o: &Self) -> bool {
        self.0 == o.0
    }
}
impl<T> Eq for Id<T> {}

pub struct IdCollection<T>(HashMap<Id<T>, T>);
impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a IdCollection<T> {
    type Item = (&'a Id<T>, &'a T);
    type IntoIter = std::collections::hash_map::Iter<'a, Id<T>, T>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.0.iter()
    }
}

impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a mut IdCollection<T> {
    type Item = (&'a Id<T>, &'a mut T);
    type IntoIter = std::collections::hash_map::IterMut<'a, Id<T>, T>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.0.iter_mut()
    }
}

impl<T> std::ops::Index<Id<T>> for IdCollection<T> {
    type Output = T;
    fn index(&self, id: Id<T>) -> &Self::Output {
        self.0.get(&id).unwrap()
    }
}

impl<T> std::ops::IndexMut<Id<T>> for IdCollection<T> {
    fn index_mut(&mut self, id: Id<T>) -> &mut Self::Output {
        self.0.get_mut(&id).unwrap()
    }
}

impl<T> std::ops::Index<&Id<T>> for IdCollection<T> {
    type Output = T;
    fn index(&self, id: &Id<T>) -> &Self::Output {
        self.0.get(id).unwrap()
    }
}

impl<T> std::ops::IndexMut<&Id<T>> for IdCollection<T> {
    fn index_mut(&mut self, id: &Id<T>) -> &mut Self::Output {
        self.0.get_mut(id).unwrap()
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you have provided [does not produce the error you are asking about](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a6243eec030df060b063e58e797229b7)

Comment: It's great that you have the solution to your question! You should post it as an answer rather than an edit to your question and then potentially accept that answer. That way, the question shows up as solved in search results, people can vote on your answer, and your solution can be more helpful to future people with the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you try to achieve, then I have to tell you, that it is a bit more complex than you originally thought it would be.

First of all, you have to realise, that if you like to use a `HashMap` then the type of the key required to be *hashable* and *comparable*.  Therefore the generic type parameter `T` in `Id<T>` has to be bound to those traits in order to make `Id` hashable and comparable.

The second thing you need to understand is that there are two different traits to deal with the indexing operator: [`Index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) for immutable data access, and [`IndexMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.IndexMut.html) for mutable one.

```rust
use std::{
    marker::PhantomData,
    collections::HashMap,
    cmp::{
        Eq,
        PartialEq,
    },
    ops::{
        Index,
        IndexMut,
    },
    hash::Hash,
};

#[derive(PartialEq, Hash)]
struct Id<T>(usize, PhantomData<T>)
    where T: PartialEq + Hash;

impl<T> Eq for Id<T>
    where T: PartialEq + Hash
{}

struct IdCollection<T>(HashMap<Id<T>, T>)
    where T: PartialEq + Hash;

impl<T> Index<Id<T>> for IdCollection<T>
    where T: PartialEq + Hash
{
    type Output = T;

    fn index(&self, id: Id<T>) -> &Self::Output
    {
        self.0.get(&id).unwrap()
    }
}

impl<T> IndexMut<Id<T>> for IdCollection<T>
    where T: PartialEq + Hash
{
    fn index_mut(&mut self, id: Id<T>) -> &mut Self::Output
    {
        self.0.get_mut(&id).unwrap()
    }
}

fn main()
{
    let mut i = IdCollection(HashMap::new());
    i.0.insert(Id(12, PhantomData), 99i32);
    println!("{:?}", i[Id(12, PhantomData)]);
    i[Id(12, PhantomData)] = 54i32;
    println!("{:?}", i[Id(12, PhantomData)]);
}
```

It may seem a bit surprising, but `IndexMut` is not designed to insert an element into the collection but to actually modify an existing one.  That's the main reason why `HashMap` does not implement `IndexMut` -- and that's also the reason why the above example uses the `HashMap::insert` method to initially place the data.  As you can see, later on, when the value is already available we can modify it via the `IdCollection::index_mut`.

Comment: Yeah between the `Index` instead of `IndexMut`, plus the wrong signature (I was returning `Self::Output` instead of `&Self::Output`... By the way, `T` doesn't need any constraint since I'm not using it (as just use it as a type tag). I'm gonna edit my question with the code I've got now. Thanks :]

Comment: Sure, you can provide your own hashing for `Id` which would just use `usize` -- but I could not know whether this was a simplified dummy code or the actual implementation, so I took the liberty and provide the most generic solution.